# Mongoose Query Builder .or not returning expected results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, query-builder, or-operator

**Context** 
I'm building a query where a user can enter a range of dates to search for 'Player' documents.  The query should return any players whose start and end dates overlap with the queried dates.  I'm doing this by using an OR condition where either the player's end date is after the query's start date or the player's start date is before the query's end date.  Both dates in the query are optional, allowing the user to specify only an end date or a start date, or neither to return all relevant documents.

**Problem** 
The query works when only one of the two query dates are specified (see screenshots below).  However, it returns all documents if both dates are specified (functionally ignoring both query parameters).

**Code**

```
let query = Player.find({'casino': user.casino});
let queryArray = [];
if(req.body.startDate) {
        queryArray.push({playerEndDtm: {$gt: moment(req.body.startDate).toDate()}});
}
if(req.body.endDate) {
    queryArray.push({playerStartDtm: {$lt: moment(req.body.endDate).endOf('day').toDate()}});
}
if(queryArray.length > 0) {
    query.or(queryArray);
}
```

**Screenshots** 
When both query dates are specified:
[image] 
Results: 
[image]

When only 1 query date is specified:
[image] 
Results: 
[image]

Can anyone help me determine what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You need 2 conditions in endate query.  I am adding as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(req.body.endDate) {
    queryArray.push({playerStartDtm: {$lt: 
    moment(req.body.endDate).endOf('day').toDate()}});
}
```

In the above query you are justing checking less then the end date. You need to check range between dates:

```
 ({ playerStartDtm : { $gt :  expression, $lt : expression}})
```

Comment: I want the query to return any documents that overlap the dates.  The adjustment you made above would exclude players who start before the start date, but end after it.  That's why I have the separate check on the end date.  Are you saying that I need to include both a $gt and an $lt expression when I query on dates?

Comment: Yes. Both $gt and an $lt expression when you query on dates. Because you are looking for date range.

Comment: Thanks.  But that still doesn't explain why it works when I only enter a single date.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: When you query for end date, it is picking date without considering the start date. You should be looking for end date after the start date .i.e End date is always greater than start date. 
When you enter single  date, your query works bcoz there is no date boundry.

Comment: Oh my gawd you're right.   Thank you for taking the time to help me understand.